# How can I return to a specified URL after login in Laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and want to return the user to a user-specified URL after login.

I am using a lot of JavaScript and want to return to a specific URL, that isn't the URL the user is trying to access, after they have logged in. The URL is different depending on user action.

For example:
`/login?r=/come/here/after/login`

I can pass this URL to the login screen, but I can't find a way to pass it through to the auth controller for redirection after login is successful.

Comment: return redirect()->intended('your-url'); in your authenticate function or you just want to redirect to url which will be passed with login url only ?

Comment: I’d simply store it in the session … (Sure, that can lead to unexpected results, if the user has multiple tabs open, and triggers the login process in more than one of them. But how likely is that really …?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would create a custom auth middleware just for the custom redirected routes:

```
class PostLoginRedirect
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {

        $response = $next($request);

        if (\Auth::id() && isset($request->r)) {
             // Return the new route redirect.
             return redirect($request->r);
        }

        // Return the custom one in case r? don't exists.
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Declare your new middleware on app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'login-redirect' => \YourNamespace\PostLoginRedirect::class
];
```

And add to your routes:

```
$this->post('login', ['middleware' => 'login-redirect', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login']);
```

Maybe you need to do a minor change but must work :)

Comment: That's not going to work.  It's different for every link, and it's passed as a query string

Comment: hmm, `\Auth::id()` is always `null` inside the middleware.  Looks like I'm not logged in at this point

Comment: Sorted, need to call `$next($request)` first: `$response = $next($request);` and then I can access `Auth`

Comment: Wow, sorry it was a mistake I fix it now :)